# To make a field read only for all except user with certain role in Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore

I have an item with a certain template field. When a non-admin user login in the filed should remain read-only. But the same field in the item should be editable for users with a specific role. Please help me with this. I am stuck with this for more than 2 days.

Answer (score 1):

In Sitecore below the Templates item where the field is defined, you can give

> Field Write

rights on the Field item, deny right for roles you want read-only. but remember deny rights have more priority over access right.

See the the [inheritance access right](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/security_and_administration/access_rights/the_inheritance_access_right) for creating an inheritance structure to explicitly give write access to each field by the roles.